# How to prevent high side PMOS from glitching?

Tags: mosfet, switches, mosfet-driver, pmos

I want to use a PMOS-Transistor as a high side switch like so:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fU6Giu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

But when I tested this circuit on a breadboard, there was always a small voltage spike at the output, when the 12V where switched on. Since this will be used as a control signal to external devices it must not glitch when powered on.

Is there anything I can do to improve this circuit? Or are PMOS-Transistors entirely unsuitable for this purpose. I already thought about using NMOS instead, but then I would have to add a charge pump to get above 12V which would add an undesirable amount of cost and complexity.

Since I do not have to source a lot of current (/the voltage drop is not that relevant), would it help to use BJTs instead?

**UPDATE:**

I did some more measurements and the amplitude and duration of the spike is proportional to the load resistance. Removing M2 did not change the result.

This means that this is not a suitable solution for me because the load resistance can be very high. With `R_Load > 10k` the output voltage does not even go down to 0V.

So the real question seems to be: what are the alternatives? BJTs?

**UPDATE 2:**

The question is not why this happens (I know it happens because it takes a few microseconds to charge the gate), but how to prevent it. Another PMOS transistor will not help, because it could make the problem less severe, but it will still be there. Especially with light loads.

So again my question: Can I somehow make this better? What happens if I replace M1 with a PNP-Transistor and a base resistor (I don't have one to test at the moment)?

Comment: What helps if you understand **what causes** the glitch instead of trying whatever is possible. Very likely the voltage spike is caused by a combination of fast switching and Gate-Drain and Gate-Source capacitances of the NMOS transistors. If you switch on M2 the gate of M1 is abruptly connected to ground. I would add a series resistor of 1 kohm with the gate of M1 so that its gate cannot discharge/charged so quickly and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: @FakeMoustache: I think I know what causes the glitch. It has nothing to do with M2. I think rDS of M1 is low until the gate of M1 is charged to the same voltage as source.

Comment: Describe the voltage spike or better still, take a picture and post it. Fully describe the load conditions, the length of wires and the power supply too. All potential contributory factors.

Comment: OP - FakeM is telling you *why* M1's gate is low - M2's drain-source capacitance is pulling M1's gate down for whatever period it takes R1 to charge it up. I'm 99.9% certain that if you disconnect M2 then you won't see any power-on glitch.

Comment: @brhans I think you may be mistaken, when the 12 V turns on, M2 is shorting its own capacitance out so that has zero effect. FakeMoustache is talking about M1's gate capacitance however, I don't believe that is the likely problem either!

Comment: @Andyaka - but he's referring to M2 as an NMOS - why would it be shorting its own capacitance at power-on if it's off?

Comment: The circuit will only work properly if M1 is a PMOS and M2 is an NMOS. My suggestion was to add a gate resistor to PMOS M1.

Comment: You need to look at your PMOS data sheet. The relevant item is Idss, zero gate voltage drain source leakage. For instance, an IRF9630 has a maximum leakage of 1 mA. Also, you can look for drain-source capacitance (Cds), although this is usually found indirectly by subtracting Crss from Coss. This can easily be in the 100's of pF, and if you are applying a sharp input edge, of course you're getting a load spike. Read the data sheets.

Comment: You juat need a push pull complementary output stage.What about some old fashioned CMOS gate 4000 series?